# All Mongoose functions silently timeout after NPM update

Tags: node.js, mongodb, npm, mongoose

We were on Mongoose 5.9.1 for some time and I thought I try to update it to the newest version gradually and test everything.

However, after updating to 5.10.13 all our Jest tests, that were accessing in some way the database were failing. It seems that all Mongoose functions (find, findOne, bulkWrite, ...) were started, but never returned, so JEST failed after the timeout.

True enough, when starting the application as normal, our Express routes were just failing with a "Socket Hang Up", no error message or anything from Mongoose. After doing a "npm install mongoose@5.9.1" the error was still there, which is pretty weird.

I am honestly not sure where to look for the problem...

Comment: Hey man, did you find the cause of the issue. I am experiencing similar. I upgraded mongoose from 5.9.21 to 5.10.10. My functional tests started throwing a timeout error. With mongoose 5.9 everything works perfect.